# But what is with the other cyclic groups? Doesn't one also have to consider them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

I'm currently reading a textbook about abstract algebra.

There is a proof that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

This proof is using the fact as  every proof I have found on the Internet that all cyclic groups have the form $ \langle a\rangle=\{a^n\}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But I don't think that this is true, because only cyclic groups under multiplication have this form.

But what is with the other cyclic groups? Doesn't one also have to consider them?

Comment: It's not multiplication. When we have an abstract group, its operation (whatever it is) is usually denoted by $gh$. This is just a notation, it doesn't have to be actual multiplication. Of course, if you work with a specific group, you will use the usual notation of this group. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$ the operation is addition, and so if you apply the operation $n$ times on an integer $a$, the result will be denoted by $na$. But in an abstract group, this is usually denoted by $a^n$.

Comment: Ok, I see thank you!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: That is an *answer*, @Mark, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's just notation.

For each group $(G,\ast)$ (for any binary operation $\ast$ that defines a group on the set $G$), we may write the set $G$ under *concatenation* (which is the fancy term for putting symbols next to each other **and it does not always denote multiplication**), via the inclusion map $\iota(g)=g$ because
$$\iota(g\ast h)=\iota(g)\iota(h)=gh$$ for *arbitrary* $g,h\in G$.${}^\dagger$ Powers, multiples, *etc.*, depending on $\ast$, are then simply $g^n$ for *arbitrary* $g\in G, n\in\Bbb Z$.

This is to save time on writing/typing.

Concatenation may as well be the arbitrary notation to use for an arbitrary group, by fiat. In that case, we write $G$ instead of $(G,\ast)$ when the context is clear.

---

$\dagger$: Here $\iota$ is known as an *isomorphism*.